# Reading a particular config element using c#?

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration, xmldocument

Here i have a config file and i am reading that config elements in c#. What i need is to read all the elements based on the host `<Brand Host="localhost:64995">`  .For example if the host is localhost:64995 i need the nodes inside it like     `<add Name="aaa" BrandId="13" />`

Here is my config

```
<SingleSignOn>
        <Brands>
          <Brand Host="localhost:64995">
          <add Name="aaa" BrandId="1" />
          </Brand>
          <Brand Host="aaaaa">
            <add Name="bbbb" BrandId="2"  />
          </Brand>
        </Brands>
      </SingleSignOn>
```

and my code

```
string host = GetHostUrl();
   List<ConfigurationContract> branditems = null;
   XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
   xdoc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + "SSO.config");
   XmlNode xnodes = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/SingleSignOn/Brands");
   foreach (XmlNode xnn in xnodes.ChildNodes)
   {

   }
```

and here i will pass the host value from this `string host = GetHostUrl();` and if the host value matches the element in the config it should read and get that element.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `foreach`, you can use

```
if (xnn.Attributes["Host"].Value == host)
{
  foreach (XmlNode i in xnn.ChildNodes) // i is the child node inside <Brand Host="localhost:64995"></Brand>
  {
    if (i.Attributes["Name"].Value == "aaa") // or even i.Attributes["BrandId"].Value == "1"
    {
       // Do your stuff
    }
  }
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I would recommend doing `(string)xnn.Attribute["Host"]` and `(string)i.Attributes["Name"]` in case either the element or the attribute is not there.  This will prevent a null reference exception.